OSM-Data but only with polygons
I need a map with only polygons in it. If I download OSM Data, streets, waterways and railways are line layers. Since OSM shows a street with a certain width, there have to be some data about the width. I wonder if there is a way to get the OSM as an area-filling polygonlayer.
The alternative way is to buffer the lines, but this is very time expensive.

you can try https://a-b-street.github.io/osm2streets/

"Since OSM shows a street with a certain width, there have to be some data about the width." The width is derived from the tags by the rendering rules https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OpenStreetMap_Carto/Lines.
